# Facebook api batch for revalidate multiple access token

Tags: facebook, api, batch-file, access-token

I want to make a Facebook batch call to read registered users walls.

As far as I know, I need to especify the user access token in the body of each call in batch. But with offline_access depreciation, I need to revalidate all users access token before use it.

So, if I am batching multiple calls, it makes no sense to revalidate each access token separatly (like discribed here: http://goo.gl/M3Jrr).

How can I revalidate those access token faster?

Answer (score 0):

> How can I re-validate those access token faster?

You **can't**. Once a user access token is expired, you need to capture this and get the user to engage with your app to *refresh* the access token.

Now I don't know why would you need to read your registered users walls in bulk which, depending on your motives, might be a violation of Facebook policies but I suppose in the response body of the batch call you should receive a clear error about an expired access token and hence, for example, add a flag in the DB for those (*inactive*) users to re-engage them later.

Comment: I am using Facebook Real Time Update. I want to search for a tag in posts of all users that already accepted the read_stream permissions. So, I do not think that violates Facebook policies.
Anyway, I do not think that user have to engage with my app again. The Facebook API allows the app to revalidate the token "app-side", I just want to make it just once for many users.

Comment: No, the Facebook API doesn't allow such actions. You can only request a long-lived access token but once this expires, the user ***should*** interact with your app to get a fresh token. It seems that you are building a *listening* tool, which is exactly what Facebook won't allow you to do (because it's not built around the *user experience*)!

Comment: Well, I think there is a misunderstanding...
I know my app can only request a long-lived access token when user come back. But an access token expires every 2 hours. So, to make app-side actions (like read user wall) I need to refresh that access token. All the oficial explanation is here: http://goo.gl/M3Jrr
And I actually can read users' wall. There is nothing wrong with it. There is a api for that: http://goo.gl/ZsuaA
In Facebook's words: "The Graph API supports Realtime Updates... Your app can then cache data and receive updates, rather than continuously polling Facebook’s servers."

Comment: No, the long-lived access token is valid for **60 days**! This is [how to get it](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/extending-tokens/). Of course you *can* read and write things to the users wall but you should be careful with your app design that's all what I am saying. (Your app might be very helpful, I'm just giving you a heads-up :) )